# how do I play mp3 file?

Tags: ruby, mp3, playback, background-music

How can I write a script in ruby which plays mp3 file (background-music) when executed from command-line?

I tried this

```
run = "mplayer #{"/Users/bhushan/resume/m.mp3"} -ao sdl -vo x11 -framedrop -cache 16384 -cache-min 20/100"
system(run)
```

but it is not working also, above is player specific. what if user don't have mplayer installed. Id there a better way?

Comment: what does it say when it doesn't work? does it work from the command line?

Comment: Since you seem to be on a Mac, why are you using `-vo x11`?

Comment: it doesn't say anything. return value is `false` of last statement

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually just do

```
pid = fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q', file }
```

Comment: on mac-os-x

    pid = fork{ exec 'afplay', file }

Answer (score 7):

Try this way: this uses Shoes to do the magic, it's all you need i hope
http://rubylearning.com/blog/2008/05/31/a-teeny-weeny-mp3-player-using-ruby-and-shoes/

```
#my_mp3player01.rb
Shoes.app do
  button( 'play' ){ @v.play }
  button( 'pause' ){ @v.pause }
  button( 'stop' ){ @v.stop }
  @v = video "C:/rubyprograms/mp3player/ruby.mp3"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write ruby code that uses different players.

For instance, a class I use:

https://gist.github.com/2217498

Rather than mplayer, one could use sox or vlc or something else.

In your **example**, you can always extend your code. Rather than hardcoded mplayer, you could read this from a yaml file, which you can dynamically change.

You can also try to use gstreamer via ruby-gtk directly.

But remember, ruby in itself can not play audio files.

It would be cool if someone would be able to create a pure ruby player though.

Answer (score 1):

here's how I play them with jruby and an external jar: https://github.com/rdp/jruby-swing-helpers/blob/master/spec/play_mp3_audio.spec.rb